# Is this correct: "In his store, one you've(?) often had the pleasure of visiting, was an employee you've never met before."

Tags: grammaticality

Is the use of "you've" correct in that sentence? I know it's a very simple question, but I cannot for the life of me figure out the usage of "you've" in past tense writing.

Comment: You have two instances of *you've*. The first is just right, but the second, not so much. All you need is 'an employee *you* never met before.'

Comment: @YosefBaskin It (the 2nd *you've*) might depend on the context. If it's taken as a statement in the omniscient perspective, *you'd* would be better. But if it's taken as direct speech, I think *you've* works. Consider: "*Hey Bob, I know someone you've never met before*".

Comment: There seems to be a register mismatch here, between the two contracted forms *you've* (contractions in general tending to informality) and the elegant Verb-Subject word-order inversion of the last part. A register mismatch is no grammatical error, but still odd and most often worth avoiding.

Comment: It’s hard to imagine a scenario where this is what I’d be saying to someone.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you've put isn't too bad in the context of what you're asking.  It might sound more natural without the contraction (i.e. "one you have often had the pleasure of visiting").

I have a couple of minor issues with the grammar though:

- "one you've often had the pleasure of visiting" - "had" implies that the visiting has ended.  In your story, this would only be appropriate if you would never visit it again.  I would change this to "one you often have the pleasure of visiting" to imply that the pleasure will continue.
- "was an employee you've never met before" - since you're using the past tense ("was"), it's more correct to use the past perfect/pluperfect tense here, i.e. "was an employee you had never met before", to imply that the not-meeting-before state ended in the past.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct in the first half, but rather clumsy and unnatural. "one you've often had the pleasure of visiting" is perfectly good in British English, and does NOT imply the visits have ended - the use of the present perfect sees to that. "had" is the past participle of the auxiliary verb "have". I do understand that the present perfect is not much used in north American English though. "You've" in the second part though should be replaced by "you'd" - but it would really be better to start again.